# adding JWT token in request in reactive way in webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using `WebClient` to call Rest API Which are secured by JWT token. 
**//To get Token**

```
JwtToken token = client.post()
                .uri("")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "XXX")
                        .with("password", "XXXXX"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(JwtToken.class)
                .onErrorMap(e -> new Exception("Error While getting Token", e))
                .blockLast();
```

**//Call secure API**

```
 WebClient client = consorsWebClientBuilder
                .defaultHeaders(token.bearer())
                .build();

              client
                .get()
                .uri(someURI)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
```

i am calling  `Block` in reactive chain, so web flux is not happy and saying

**block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-client-epoll-12**

How can i add token in reactive way ? 
Note, I Can create Filter but still in filter also i need to call `Block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I used map for this, not the best solution but does the work

Mono<JwtToken>  token = client.post()
                .uri("")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "XXX")
                        .with("password", "XXXXX"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMon(JwtToken.class)
                .onErrorMap(e -> new Exception("Error While getting Token", e))


return token
     .flatMap(token -> callApi(request, token));
```

Comment: You can use the following

    client.get().headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token.bearer()))

You can get references here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/webclient.html#webclient

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way to add it by implementing the `ExchangeFilterFunction` in your `WebClient` using `filter`, like below:

```
WebClient.builder().filter(setJWT());

private ExchangeFilterFunction setJWT() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor((clientRequest) -> {
            ClientRequest authorizedRequest = ClientRequest.from(clientRequest).header("AUTHORIZATION","{LOGIC TO GET THE TOKEN}").build();
            return Mono.just(authorizedRequest);
        });
    }
```

This implementation will take the request before actually calling the API and add the JWT token.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `doOnSuccess`

```
client.post()
      .uri("")
      .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", "XXX")
                    .with("password", "XXXXX"))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToFlux(JwtToken.class)
      .onErrorMap(e -> new Exception("Error While getting Token", e))
      .doOnSuccess(jwtToken -> {
                client.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "bearer " + jwtToken)
                      .get()
                      ...
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this, as i wanted to return response ended up using map. As I cant return value from doOnSuccess